# How to untrap after a trap command

Tags: bash

I have an error trap as follows:

```
trap failed ERR
function failed {
    local r=$?
    set +o errtrace
    set +o xtrace
    echo "###############################################"
    echo "ERROR: Failed to execute"
    echo "###############################################"
    # invokes cleanup
    cleanup
    exit $r
}
```

There is a part of my code where I do expect an error:

```
command1
command2
command3
set +e #deactivates error capture
command4_which_expects_error
set -e #re-activates error capture
command5
```

Overall I need to ignore the trap during the execution of **command4_which_expects_error**

The **set +e** does not seem to disable the trap. Any other ways to "untrap" and then "re-trap" ?

Answer (score 77, accepted):

Here is what you can find in the *trap* manual:

> The KornShell uses an ERR trap that is triggered whenever set -e would cause an exit.

That means it is not triggered by `set -e`, but is executed in the same conditions. Adding `set -e` to a *trap* on ERR would make your script exit after executing the trap.

To remove a trap, use:

```
trap - [signal]
```

Comment: Just to emphasize, `signal` is optional (which is why it is placed in square brackets). You can use `trap -` to remove all traps, I believe.

Comment: KornShell, where is this mentioned??

Comment: @JoshuaPinter `trap -` returns usage help. See my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64786665/658497) how to unset all trap signals.

Comment: This syntax seems less portable than 'trap [signal]'. On at least one legacy platform (SCO Openserver 5.0.7 MP5), in a /bin/sh script, 'trap - [signal]' can return an error message like '-: not found' though this message does not occur if used in an interactive session.  An error message is avoided by using 'trap [signal]' to clear traps. This alternate syntax is documented work on modern platforms. For example, 'man bash' says 'If arg is absent (and there is a single sigspec) or -, each specified signal is reset to its original disposition  (the value it had upon entrance to the shell)'.

Comment: Note: According to `help set`, `set -E` is needed if you want to use `trap - ERR` in a function (for example, something with a name like "disable_err_trap", as a counterpart to "enable_err_trap"). Otherwise the `trap - ERR` in the function fails to disable the trap outside the function scope.

Answer (score 11):

To ignore the failure of a command that you know may fail (but don't necessarily need), you can cause the line to always succeed by appending `|| true`.

Example:

```
#!/bin/bash

set -e

failed() {
    echo "Trapped Failure"
}
trap failed ERR

echo "Beginning experiment"
false || true
echo "Proceeding to Normal Exit"
```

Results

```
Beginning experiment
Proceeding to Normal Exit
```

Comment: One can also use the [colon/null utility](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html) (Ctrl-f "null utility") for this purpose: `|| :` It's shorter and has the benefit of not needing to spawn a process, as `true` is typically `/bin/true` and `:` is always a builtin, per POSIX.

Answer (score 10):

You can use this `trap` to reset `trap` set earlier:

```
trap '' ERR
```

Comment: `help trap` says use `''` to ignore, `-` to reset to default behaviour.

Answer (score 2):

To unset **all** trapped signals, you can run "trap - signal" in a loop:

```
trap | awk '{ print $NF }' | while read SIG ; do trap - $SIG ; done
```

Comment: Without external commands: `trap - $(compgen -A signal)`

Comment: Granted, this is tagged 'bash'.  This is not portable.  On some platforms trap suppresses output if it is in a pipe (i.e. SCO Openserver 5.0.7 MP5).  This behavior was observed under sh, ksh, and bash.  Even if that behavior were somehow handled, when invoked under 'sh' output is in the form '15: cleanup 1' where 15 is the trap number, so $NF definitely would not do the right thing there. Under ksh and bash, trap does output the name of the signal such that $NF would work if the pipe didn't squelch output.  Also, commenter, compgen is a shell-specific command that does not exist in all shells.